# Google OAuth The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#, .net, oauth

On Wednesday our Google OAuth integration was working normally and on Thursday it stopped with Google returning:

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

No code changes have been made.  Token and TokenSecret are returned from https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken successfully but attempts to access https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/email get the above error.

This is Google OAuth version 1 which according to documentation is still supported 'till September 2014.

Anyone else getting the same issue with Google OAuth?

Comment: Did you find the issue?